# Attach validation rule to form field programmatically

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using [VeeValidate](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate) to do some validation on a form made with [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/). I have it set up to display a span with the error message related to the input where the error occurred.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="date" 
         class="form-control" 
         name="panelData.AnalysisDate" 
         data-vv-as="Analysis Date" 
         v-model="panelData.AnalysisDate"
         v-validate="'required|date_format:YYYY-MM-DD'">
</div>
<span v-show="errors.has('panelData.AnalysisDate')" class="redText">{{errors.first('panelData.AnalysisDate')}}</span>
```

All of the inputs are set up the same way and they are all working correctly.
The issue arises when I try to add a validation rule to the above input that requires a [date-between](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/rules.html#rule-date_between) rule that uses a year from today's date as the max value.

`date_between:{min,max}`

The `v-validate` attribute takes in a string of the validation rules delimted by a `|`. There is a way to dynamically add rules via the validator instance that gets automatically attached to the Vue instance.

`$validator.attach({field}, {rules list}, {options})`

I tried to do the code below in both the ['created' and 'mounted' life cycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Lifecycle-Hooks) and neither yielded the results I am looking for.

```
var today = new Date();
var yearFromToday = new Date(today.getFullYear() + 1, today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
    
var yearFromTodayStr = yearFromToday.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
//'this' refers to the current view instance
//'panelData' is the name of an object in my component's data object
this.$validator.attach('panelData.AnalysisDate', 'date_between:2001-01-01,' + yearFromTodayStr, {
        prettyName: 'Analysis Date'
    });
```

The annoying thing is, the code works because if I use the console (chrome) to insert my code, it gives me the desired results once everything is rendered on the screen. I am not sure if I am using the correct lifecycle hooks.

[image]

Comment: Provide the code for attaching this, as well as how you create the validator. As I can see here http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/api.html#validator there is another way to do `attach`. What is `this.$validator`? What hooks you're using - one for directive or one for component?

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this feels hacky but I couldn't get it to work with my original approach.

For date fields that required a dynamic range I ended up using the directive style rules string and concatenated a computed property.

For example:

```
  computed: {
    ninetyNineYearsAgo() {
      return new Date().getFullYear() - 99;
    },
    eighteenYearsAgoFormatted() {
      let eighteenYearsAgo = new Date().getFullYear() - 18;
      let todayISODate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
      return eighteenYearsAgo + '-' + todayISODate.split('-')[1] + '-' + todayISODate.split('-')[2];
    }
  }

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="date" 
         class="form-control" 
         name="panelData.AnalysisDate" 
         data-vv-as="Analysis Date" 
         v-model="panelData.AnalysisDate"
         v-validate="'date_format:YYYY-MM-DD|date_between:' + ninetyNineYearsAgo +'-01-01,'+ eighteenYearsAgoFormatted + ',true'">
</div>
```